# Get specific part of string

Tags: c#

I got this string output and i need to get only the token value next to "access_token", this is the string text:

> "{\"access_token\":\"ef64ed9cccb9a267d7fbdf91699509fbf4a577d3\",\"expires_in\":3600,\"token_type\":\"bearer\",\"scope\":null,\"refresh_token\":\"f029808be305fcf4052645615648f2f7ec9b475a\"}"

I already managed to get only this part

> "{\"access_token\":\"ef64ed9cccb9a267d7fbdf91699509fbf4a577d3\"

With this

```
 text = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
 string[] xx = text.Split(',');
 string test = xx[0];
```

Now how can i manage to get only the ef64ed9cccb9a267d7fbdf91699509fbf4a577d3 (in this case). I already tryed to split by "\" but i get some syntax erros ..

Thanks btw guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your text will have always that format you can try that sample :

```
 text = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
 string[] xx = text.Split('\"');
 string test = xx[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't recommended, but to split based on a backslash you need to escape the backslash. So split based on "\\".

```
string[] xx = text.Split('\\');
```

If that doesn't work try something like:

```
string[] xx = Regex.Split(text, "\\");
```

you'll need to use System.Text.RegularExpressions for that

Comment: its not that simple split can only be by one character mate

Comment: you should still be able to split based on an escaped character. I changed the quotes on the above. Otherwise try a Regex.Split()